# when I use xml object my app crashes

Tags: java, android

i declared b1,b2,b3... up here ...
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {}

```
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction() .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment(
        )).commit();


    // Definiranje botuna
     b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.broj1);
     b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.broj2);
     b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.broj3);
     b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.broj4);
     b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.broj5);
     b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.broj6);
     b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.broj7);
     b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.broj8);
     b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.broj9);
     b0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.broj0);
     bPlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
     bMinus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
     bPuta= (Button) findViewById(R.id.puta);
     bDjeljeno = (Button) findViewById(R.id.djeljeno);
     bKvadrat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kvadrat);
     bIzracunaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.izracunaj);

    //Definiranje polja
     text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.polje1);
     text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.polje2);
     text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.polje3);




     b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {               
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
              text1.setText("1");
            }}

             );







            }


















@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {







}
```

}

when I delete OnclickListener my app works fine, I`m freaking out. almost two days I'm trying to find what i did wrong, but everything seems right to me. its not just onclicklistener , when i refer to edittext or textview ( something like .getText). i just dont know what to do. my setContentView is refering to right activity i triple checked it, if anyone knows what am i doing wrong please help :s

this is my entire xml

```
                    .
                    .
                    .
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
           >

             <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/polje1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="                                                                              "
        android:height="30dp"


        />

             <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/polje2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="                                                                              "
        android:height="30dp"


        />

             <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/polje3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="                                                                              "
        android:height="30dp"


        />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/broj1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
              />


        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/broj2"
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:textStyle="bold"
        />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/broj3"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
             android:textStyle="bold"
           />
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="3" >
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/broj4"
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
             android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/broj5"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/broj6"
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
             android:textStyle="bold"
        />

        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="3" >
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/broj7"
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
             android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/broj8"
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/broj9"
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
             android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="3" >
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/broj0"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
             android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/minus"
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
             android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="3" >
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/puta"
            android:text="*"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
             android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/djeljeno"
            android:text="/"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/kvadrat"
            android:text="x²"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
             android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="3" >
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/izracunaj"
            android:text="IZRACUNAJ"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textStyle="bold"
        />

</LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Well what does the log show?

Comment: Please add the trace error and your xml file.

Comment: please can you show us your xml file? is possible that it have some error

Comment: but you can just keep focus on first button because wit every other object problem is the same

Answer (score 0):

You are enclosing your code inside

```
if(savedInstanceState == null){

}
```

This isn't the place where you should be declaring variables in your onCreate. That's the place where you should be restoring the state of the Activity.

If you don't need to restore the state, you can entirely remove this check. Otherwise, move all your code out of that block that doesn't have anything to do with restoring state.

**Edit:**

I see you are adding a fragment to your Activity, but still, you seem to be doing the bulk of the task in your activity. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: i did it, but my app still crashes

Comment: Post your stacktrace please

Comment: i am sorry, im am new to android programming, so im not really clear what you are asking? im am just trying to add some function to my button

Comment: I might be wrong, but I guess your intention isn't to add a PlaceHolderFragment. Try removing this code: ` getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();`

Comment: when i delete that part and onclicklistener my app starts but it isnt showing anything just white screen

Comment: In that case undo deleting that part and move your code that wires up your buttons or textviews or whatever to the PlaceHolderFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Do some change, first find your views outside the savedInstanceState condition:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.broj1);
     TextView e1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.polje1);
     // other views

}
```

**UPDATE:**

Remove this line:

```
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction() .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
```

Also, **check that activity_main is the right layout** which contains all your LinearLayout, Buttons, Textviews etc.

Comment: i tried that way too, but then my broj1clicked isnt recognised

Comment: when i do that it is running when i delete 
   b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {               
             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
              
              text1.setText("1");
               
             }}
        ); but wit that command it crashes

Comment: OMG, thank you:DD, i just typed in fragment_main and now it works thank you so much, i cant believe i made that mistake :D

Comment: I knew that! ^^ Glad it's working now - also, I tried your layout and nothing is wrong with the `weight` attribute. It displays well!

Answer (score 0):

You gotta put your Objects references such as Button out of your IF, because of savedinstance it's not null, it will never reference it.

This code should work for you, Just remember to match the correct names on your main xml:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.broj1);
    TextView e1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.polje1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {               
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            e1.setText("Button 1 Clicked");
        }
    });
}
```

Test it out.

Comment: i did it, but still crashes

Comment: i did, im just trying to make when i press button that it changes TextView`s text